# nested validation for uniqueness doesn't work in rails 4 project

Tags: activerecord, nested-forms, nested-attributes, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have two models - `Category` and `Property` with has_balongs_to_many association. I use `nested_form` gem. So, Category has many properties. When I create new category I can create properties.

Category model `category.rb`:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base 
  # relationships
  has_many :categories_properties
  has_many :properties, through: :categories_properties, inverse_of: :categories

  # allows to create and destroy nested objects
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :properties, allow_destroy: true

  # validation
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 128 }, uniqueness: true
end
```

Property model `property.rb`:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  # relationships
  has_many :categories_properties
  has_many :categories, through: :categories_properties

  # validation
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 128 }, uniqueness: true
end
```

As you see a have `uniqueness: true` validation in property model.
When I'm trying to create the same properties using `rails console` or on the `category edit page` - it gives me error like "property with this name already exists." It's correct and it should be.

But on the `category new` page, when I create the same properties (as you see in screenshot) it doesn't give me errors, validation doesn't work and it creates me new category with two same properties.... What's wrong? Please help.

[image]

Here's log:

```
Started POST "/categories" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-01 14:28:19 +0300
Processing by CategoriesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"AFf8upQco8ZqJBS8QdpU9RIRpvAW1VLnBSm1bw6rxss=", "category"=>{"title"=>"Category", "description"=>"category description", "order"=>"12345", "icon"=>"http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-LOX6N2kXXaY/T5UtocrGRnI/AAAAAAAAAFU/EW_OZTHT1PI/s1600/1210167310_174374.jpg", "parent_id"=>"", "properties_attributes"=>{"1409570848547"=>{"title"=>"same properties", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1409570857024"=>{"title"=>"same properties", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Category"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.4ms)  SELECT "categories"."id", "categories"."title" FROM "categories"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories"."id", "categories"."title" FROM "categories"
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Property Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "properties"  WHERE "properties"."title" = 'same properties' LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "properties"  WHERE "properties"."title" = 'same properties' LIMIT 1
  Category Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "categories"  WHERE "categories"."title" = 'Category' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "categories" ("created_at", "description", "icon", "order", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2014-09-01 11:28:19.908849"], ["description", "category description"], ["icon", "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-LOX6N2kXXaY/T5UtocrGRnI/AAAAAAAAAFU/EW_OZTHT1PI/s1600/1210167310_174374.jpg"], ["order", 12345], ["title", "Category"], ["updated_at", "2014-09-01 11:28:19.908849"]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "properties" ("created_at", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2014-09-01 11:28:19.910971"], ["title", "same properties"], ["updated_at", "2014-09-01 11:28:19.910971"]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "categories_properties" ("category_id", "created_at", "property_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["category_id", 77], ["created_at", "2014-09-01 11:28:19.921763"], ["property_id", 90], ["updated_at", "2014-09-01 11:28:19.921763"]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "properties" ("created_at", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2014-09-01 11:28:19.947583"], ["title", "same properties"], ["updated_at", "2014-09-01 11:28:19.947583"]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "categories_properties" ("category_id", "created_at", "property_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["category_id", 77], ["created_at", "2014-09-01 11:28:19.950243"], ["property_id", 91], ["updated_at", "2014-09-01 11:28:19.950243"]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/categories/77
Completed 302 Found in 129ms (ActiveRecord: 21.8ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add validation method to category model:

```
  def properties_uniq? params
    properties = params.map{ |_,property| property[:title] }
    if properties.uniq.length < properties.length
      errors.add(:category, "Properties duplication are not allowed." ) 
      return false
    end
    true
  end
```

Check attributes in controller (when save category):

```
  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.save && @category.properties_uniq?(params[:category][:properties_attributes])
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```